# Paragraph styles changes when I copy them. Google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have one document, and I want to copy some paragraphs to another. I am using this code for it.

```
function mergeDocs(docIDs, fileName) {
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(idFolderDest);
  var newDocID = DriveApp.getFileById(idTitlesTemplate).makeCopy(fileName, folder).getId();
  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newDocID);

  var body = baseDoc.getBody();

  for (var i = 0; i < docIDs.length; ++i) {
    var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(docIDs[i]).getBody();
    var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();
    
    for (var k = 0; k < totalElements; ++k) {
      let element = otherBody.getChild(k).copy();
      let type = element.getType();
      //if (k == 2) continue;
      if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {body.appendParagraph(element); Logger.log(element.asParagraph().getTextAlignment())}
      else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) body.appendTable(element);
      else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) body.appendListItem(element);
      else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PAGE_BREAK) body.appendPageBreak(element);
      else {Logger.log(type)}
    }
    if (i < docIDs.length - 1){
      body.appendPageBreak();
    }
  }
  return newDocID;
}
```

When i run program it lose some styles, for example text style or indents.
[origin paragraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEOZP.png)
[created paragraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbQh4.png)

I tried to find solution in Internet, but i have not found anything

Comment: copy the styles too

Comment: I don't know how to copy styles. I thought that element should keep styles about itself.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute